# jQuery button to to activate DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a simple action  where a user clicks a button that says "access", rather than submitting the form, I want it to slide down a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[value=access]').click(function() {
    $('#access').slideDown();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="access" />
<div id="access">
  Here, this will slide down
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
<script>          
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        $("#mybutton").click(function() {
            $("#example").slideDown('slow');
        });
    });            
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="example" style="display: none;">
    Hello World

</div>

<button id="mybutton" >Access</button>
```